# xpath selection using scrapy to get a youtube channel id

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors

Given the following Xpath selector from a Youtube channel ,I need to extract its id

```
 response.xpath('/html/body/meta[@itemprop="channelId"]/@content')
```

which results in:

```
 <Selector xpath='/html/body/meta[@itemprop="channelId"]/@content' data='UCPeA5h9SwPCV2a0SPlXHgNA'>
```

how do i get the data in a string format using python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's work for me

```
response.xpath('/html/body/meta[@itemprop="channelId"]/@content').get()
```

Comment: If this should be an answer, please improve it by some more details.